# vector definition in struct (c++)

Tags: c++, struct

A very basic question, but i haven't found the answer yet.

I wrote an Application which is using an Array with a constant predefined Value which defines the size of this array. So but now i want to change this so that the "list" can theoretically be endless (i know that it would be practically impossible). For that I want to use a vector. But when I type the following it gives me an Error:

edit(2): Wrote accidentially const and a wrong parameter for push_back funktion, heres the final version, which gives the error.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "string"
#include "vector"

using namespace std;

struct Board {
  vector <string> myVector;
  myVector.push_back("foo");
};
```

Error Message: 
`<error-type> Board::myVector
This declaration has no storage class or type specifier.`

My thought was that vectors dont work in `structs`. I heard that structs are a plain C thing and vectors are more a C++ thing, maybe thats why it is so? But actually I have no clue, thats why I am asking here :)

edit (1):
I just gave you the visual studio error, maybe I should give you the compiler errors..:
`error C3927: '->': trailing return type is not allowed after a non-function declarator`
`error C3484: syntax error: expected '->' before the return type`
`error C3613: missing return type after '->' ('int' assumed)`
`error C3646: 'push_back': unknown override specifier`
`error C2059: syntax error: '('`
`error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'`

Comment: you put code in your structure "myVector.push_back(1);"

Comment: You declared the const vector and then try to modify it. The second: `myVector.push_back(1)` is not possible in a struct definition.

Comment: you need to start with some lessons or a book or some tutorials

Comment: Sorry `const` was a fail I made. Wrote it actually without a const, but the problem is the same.

Comment: please dont fix errors in your question after you got answers. The currently only answer is rather confusing to read, because most things it refers to are not present in your code anymore. Btw are you sure that the compiler error is from the code you show? It is a bit fishy that it complains about a `->`,  but there is none in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem are as followings:

- **(*`corrected in OP question`*)** `myVector` is defined `const`
- `myVector.push_back(1);` is not in any function body.
- **(*`corrected in OP question`*)** Value passed to `myVector.push_back(1);` is `int` but `vector` is of type `string`

Change it as following. See example program [working here](https://ideone.com/vANXVJ):

```
#include "string"
#include "vector"
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

struct Board {
    vector<string> myVector;

    void push_back(string val)
    {
        myVector.push_back(val);
    }

    void print()
    {
        for (auto it = myVector.begin(); it != myVector.end(); ++it)
            cout << " | " << *it;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Board b;
    b.push_back("Value 1");
    b.push_back("Value 2");

    b.print();

    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

**(`can you actually use push_back for a vector in a struct without creating an extra function?`)**

No. `structure` can have only `data members` and `member functions`. but you can use `initializer-list` to initialize vector as following:

```
vector<string> myVector{"IVal 1", "IVal 1"};
```

If you wants to put the initlize value always at the end then use [`vector.insert()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/) instead of [`vector.push_back()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/).

Comment: My Question is, can you actually use `push_back` for a vector in a struct without creating an extra function?

Comment: Like, everytime you create an Struct Object a vector myVector is declarated and automaticially get a value e.g. "foo" on the End of this vector